# How would I go around animating a portion of a custom UIView or CGLayer?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation, caanimation

I am looking for general idea on how I should approach this problem.

Let's say I have a custom view where I override the `drawRect` to do custom drawing. This custom drawing could be a 5x5 grid (25 squares/cells) where each cell has it's own text in it. How can I do animations such that a portion of this grid gets animated.

For example, I was all the squares in the second row and ones in fourth columns to animate rotate 360 degrees.

I am not allowed to use CollectionViews for this, I need to do my own custom drawing. So far all animations I have used are for rotating entire views. Haven't done any where I can animate portion of a view.

Some general ideas or documentations would be useful. Thank you!

Comment: Just use 25 subviews. You don't have to use a collection view for such a simple arrangement.

Comment: @robmayoff I was just using the 5x5 as an example. My actual grid is a LOT bigger.

Comment: Okay, why are you “not allowed to use CollectionViews for this”?